# How to send & receive multifiles from Codeigniter view --> controller?

Tags: codeigniter, dropzone

I am struggling with developing dropzone multifiles upload function by Codeigniter MVC format. I read lots of example about drop&drag function but cannot customize to my project. Could you guys help me?

This is my viewpage javascript code

```js
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    // Get the template HTML and remove it from the doument
    var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template"); 
    previewNode.id = "";
    var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML; // ?
    previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode); // ?
    
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzone_wrapper", { // Make the whole body a dropzone
        url: "/Wtax2/uploadfiles", // Set the url 
        thumbnailWidth: 80,
        thumbnailHeight: 80,
        parallelUploads: 20,
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
        //autoQueue: true, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
        autoQueue: false,
        previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
        clickable: ".fileinput-button" // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
    });
```

- question 1 : which method or function should i add from above code to send multifiles object to controller??
- question 2 : how it is possible to send multifiles object without using Value Object(like java)

And This is my controller code

```
public function uploadfiles(){
    $data = array();

    $data['client_name'] = "주식회사 대기업";
    $data['client_biz_no'] = null;
    $data['wtax_file_type'] = "지방소득";
    $data['all_tax'] = "지방소득세 522,280가감조정금액 0합 계 522,280";
    $data['tax_date'] = "2018.01.10";

    $res['result'] = TRUE;
    $res['msg'] = '성공';
    $res['data'] = $data;
    $res['files'] = $_FILES;
    $this->output_json($res);
}
```

- question 3 : how can I receive files sent from view page? which function do I need?
- question 4 : which function should i use to receive multifiles object?

Thank you very much for reading my questions.
All the best!!

Comment: which types of file you want to show?

Comment: Dropzone processes one file per request. so while it can process multiple files at once, each in in a different request/instance so basically just treat it as a normal upload.

Comment: @Danish Ali I want to upload pdf files!

Comment: @Alex ah you mean it looks like multifiles upload  but actually it uploads one by one? i see! which function should i use??

Comment: Just use the upload library. Dropzone has plenty of examples and there are plenty here on stack.